# Unused project references in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

[image]

How do I determine if this reference is no longer used? Since I can only see a `import` line of code. Yet Visual Basic is not telling me the assembly is no longer needed (like it does with C#).

Comment: `Tools-Options->Text Editor->Basic->Advanced->Fade out unused Imports` + (Right Click) `Quick Actions and Refactoring->Remove Unused Imports` or `Remove and Sort Imports`

Comment: @Jimi interesting that I do have that option switched on.